# Error implementing interface as anonymous inner class

Tags: java, javafx, anonymous-inner-class

I'm learning JavaFX using Intellij IDEA. When compiling the following code:

```
public class Main extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

//More code 

    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }

//More code

    });
```

I get the error message `"Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method"`. But by observation of the code, I am clearly implementing the functional interface using an anonymous inner class.

When I construct an empty `handle` method inside the `Main` class, the code works fine, but I don't believe I should have to. What is going on!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is this line:

```
public class Main extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
```

Remove the `implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>` and you're good.

You are probably confused because you have made both your `Main` class implement the interface, and you are creating an anonymous inner class that also implements the interface. This leaves you with one class that has implemented the method - the anonymous inner class. But the outer `Main` class has not implemented the method, which is why you get the error message.